# How to know when the bluetooth printer finish to print a string

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, printing, bluetooth

I'm developing a Xamarin application and I'm trying to implement a print receipt functionality, I actually have the whole code working almost perfectly but the thing is that the printer stops printing before the whole string is printed.

```
   try {

          using (BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device?.
          CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
          UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")))
          {
             bluetoothSocket?.Connect();

             if (bluetoothSocket?.IsConnected == true) {
                 var stream = bluetoothSocket?.OutputStream;
                 byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
                 stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
              }

              if (bluetoothSocket != null)
                 bluetoothSocket.Close();
          }
     }
     catch (Exception exp){

             throw exp;
     }
```

I expect to solve this problem without using a Sleep

Comment: How long is the string you need to print?

Comment: Really hard to tell but I think is maybe around 1k length, but to be honest that is a dynamic string that could be more that 1k

Comment: The printer probably has an internal buffer that you may be filling.  Try breaking up your string into smaller chunks and writing them to the stream one by one

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll try that, I'll be right back :)

Comment: Hi Jason, I just made some blocks and send the text by parts to the printer and it did work like a charm! Thank you very much.